# BizTalk 2009 - How to run a process after all messages have processed from a large disassembled file

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

We receive many large data files daily in a variety of formats (i.e. CSV, Excel, XML, etc.).  In order to process these large files we transform the incoming data into one of our standard 'collection' message classes (using XSLT and a pipeline component - either built-in or custom), disassemble the large transformed message into individual 'object' messages and then call a series of SOAP web service methods to handle business logic and database operations.

Unlike other files received, the latest file will contain all data rows each day and therefore, we have to handle the differences to prevent identical records from being re-processed each day.

I have a suitable mechanism for handling inserts and updates but am currently struggling with the deletes (where the record exists in the database but not in the latest file).

My current thought process is to flag the deleted records in the database using a 'cleanup' task at the end of the entire process but this would require a method to be called once all 'object' messages from the disassembled file have completed.

Is it possible to monitor individual messages from a multi-record file and call a method on completion of the whole file?  Currently, all research is pointing to an orchestration with some sort of 'wait' but is this the only option?

Example: File contains 100 vehicle records.  This is disassembled into 100 individual XML messages which are processed using 100 calls to a web service method.  Wish to call cleanup  operation when all 100 messages are complete.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to handle the 'all rows every day' scenario is to pre-stage the data in SQL Server where it's easier to compare the 'current' set to the 'previous' set.  The INTERSECT and EXCEPT operators make it pretty easy in most cases.

Then drain the records with a Polling statement.

Comment: Thanks boatseller...are you using BizTalk to push the data to SQL Server and then retrieve the deltas for processing?

My idea was to parse the incoming CSV to XML first (using our custom XSLT transformer component) and then pass a unique record ID and transformed XML string to the database for comparison.  This would reduce the data items (we omit a lot of what's received) and shift some processing to the database server.  The XML for the differences would be retrieved and passed to a web service.

Comment: If you can use SSIS to import the CSV, that's the way to go. It's much faster than ff-to-xml parsing and really, it's what SSIS is designed to do.  I try to keep the set comparison all in the database since that's a better tool.  Sometimes it's whole row comparison, sometimes it's ID comparison.  It depends on the specific circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

The component that does the de-batching would need to publish a start of batch message with the number of individual records and a correlation key.

The components that do the insert & update would need to publish a completion message with the same correlation key when it is completed processing.

The start of batch message would have spun up an Orchestration that would would listen for the completion messages with that correlation key and count the number, and either after it has received the correct number or after a timeout period it would call the cleanup or raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf...I like the idea of a correlation key and record count.

Only issue I have is with the failures and the idea of a timeout.  Due to variations in the load on the server and the number of records in the file, I think it could be tricky to configure a reliable timeout. Is there a way to catch and count the failed records as well as the successful ones? It would be great to account for all records (i.e. successful count + failed count = total record count).

Comment: It depends on the type of failure.  If the process that is inserting & updating is an Orchestration you could certainly catch the failures there and have your completion message have a succeed flag.  If you aren't using an Orchestration for that process you would need something subscribing to failed message.